# Powershell CSOM - to update Project Department look-up field Value

Tags: powershell, project, csom, ms-project-server-2016

I wanted to update **Project Department** Ent Custom Field value, which is of type look-up field-  ... from a csv file via/using powershell /csom.
Many projects have department field to be updated/modified & I am looking to do this by some powershell script.

But I have no luck to push Dept value from csv into project server Field (Project Department)

```
[Array]$MyArray1 = $_.Dept
$draftProject.SetCustomFieldValue($Dept,$MyArray1)
```

Ref - https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/projectserver/Update-Server-Custom-Field-00ab99a9

Appreciate any idea ...
Thanks

Comment: Was the answer helpful? Consider voting/accepting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to pwaurl/pwa/_api/ProjectServer/CustomFields
then search for Project Department
You are looking for its internalName
usually like: custom_Guid.

Project department needs to be passed as an array, with text values replaced with their guid

Comment: Thanks Yusuff,
it worked when I used the GUID of look up value of Department subitem.

Answer (score 0):

The [Q & A section](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/projectserver/Update-Server-Custom-Field-00ab99a9/view/Discussions#content) of the referenced TechNet gallery project contains a similar question and the author himself answers:

> For lookup fields (Either multi-select or not), you can only pass the
> Lookup value as an array (The array value must be the MemberValue GUID
> from the Lookup table in DB.

This should do the trick.